# How to read and sort a file to a dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a file like this:

```
 1909 Ford Model T
 1958 Ford Edsel
 1970 AMC Gremlin
 1978 AMC Pacer
```

I want to read this file to a dict and sort it likes below:

```
 Ford : ['1909', '1958']
 AMC : ['1970', '1978']
```

I tried this:

```
def get_worst_manufacturer_dict(filename):
    car_dict = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
     for key in f:
         if key == key:
    return car_dict

def test_get_worst_manufacturer_dict():
    car_dict = get_worst_manufacturer_dict('cars.txt')
    for key in sorted(car_dict):
      print (key, ':', car_dict[key])


test_get_worst_manufacturer_dict()
```

I don't know to how to fix my first def function, I actually don't have a clue.

Comment: You should specify the exception you have seen. It is an `IndentationError`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Py3 extended unpacking with `str.split()`. This assumes that all `manufacturer` are just a single word:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_worst_manufacturer_dict(filename):   
    car_dict = defaultdict(list)
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            year, manufacturer, *model = line.split()
            car_dict[manufacturer].append(year)
    return car_dict
```

This uses a `defaultdict(list)` to keep the years, you can convert back to a `dict` if necessary `return dict(car_dict)`

Answer (score 0):

you can try with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your.csv',sep=" ", header=None)
df
```

You `df`:

```
    0       1       2       3
0   1909    Ford    Model   T
1   1958    Ford    Edsel   NaN
2   1970    AMC     Gremlin NaN
3   1978    AMC     Pacer   NaN
```

Then use:

```
df.groupby(1)[0].apply(list).to_dict()
```

It will give you:

```
{'AMC': [1970, 1978], 'Ford': [1909, 1958]}
```